# How to do I enable asyncquery for developer salesforce org

Tags: permissions, feature-activation, big-object, async-soql

I get the following error when I try to run an async soql query in workbench

> {"message":"This feature is not currently enabled for this user type
>   or org: [AsyncQuery]","errorCode":"FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED"}

Where do I enable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the winter 18 release doc

> Async SOQL is included only with the licensing of additional big
>   object capacity.

Reference link:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_api_data_services_asyncsoql.htm